# How can I build include path through my dependencies?

Tags: makefile

I have a variable, `DEPS`, which is a list of libs, e.g. `libs/a libs/b`. I have my makefile set up so that everything will build in the correct order, however I also want to set a variable `INCLUDE_PATH` that will add all the libs' include directories.

Right now that looks like:

```
INCLUDE_PATH = $(foreach DEP,$(DEPS),-I$(ROOT)/$(DEP)/include )
```

Which works.

But say I have a library, `libs/c` that depends on the other two, and my app depends on it. I could always write `DEPS = libs/c libs/a libs/b` in my makefile to get the `INCLUDE_PATH` correct but is there a way to write this so that just `DEPS = libs/c` suffices and the `INCLUDE_PATH` will still be `-I../libs/c/include -I../libs/a/include -I../libs/b/include`?

Comment: Why does your main project need the `libs/a` and `libs/b` include paths? Does it use them directly? Because just using `libs/c` that itself uses them doesn't require that your main project have include paths for them. It may need to link to them (if `libs/c` doesn't include them or link to them itself) but that's a different issue.

Comment: If your makefile doesn't include the information that `libs/c` depends on `libs/a` and `libs/b` in a way that can be gotten by make itself then there isn't likely to be a way to handle this automatically.

Comment: The main project includes headers in libs/*/include, so for typing convenience we just -I all of them.

Comment: If it actively uses all three libraries then not including all three in `DEPS` seems wrong from the very start, no? It doesn't matter what `libs/c` uses (this was my earlier point). It matters what the main project uses. (Also, if you've had to carefully order statements/targets/prereqs/etc. to ensure that "everything will build in the correct order" then you have likely not written a correct makefile.)

Comment: I didn't say I had to carefully order statements, I just said that they'll build in the correct order. But it seems weird that if my dependency structure is like app --> c --> {a,b} that I have to explicitly list {c,a,b}. Especially if lots of apps depend on c, and c depends on a lot more than 2 libs... just seems a lot of excess typing.

Comment: Like I said, an app that depends on `c` but not *directly* on `a` and `b` shouldn't need to list `a` and `b` as includes and only might need to list them at link time. In that case you don't need this at all. If `app` *does* depend on `a` and `b` then it doesn't matter that `c` does also so using the fact that `c` does is *wrong*.